# Selenium python getting stuck post driver.get('URL') for Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

My selenium script is stuck post driver.get("url") and is not moving forward, later it error out.i am using below code. post executing this is paused for long, I have tried all options from the advance setting of the IE browser

```
     from selenium import webdriver
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
     import time
     from tqdm import tqdm
     email='XXXXX'
     password='XXXXX'

     options = webdriver.IeOptions()

     options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True

     driver = webdriver.Ie('C:\Program Files (x86)\selenium- 
     3.141.0\selenium\webdriver\ie\IEdriverServer.exe')

     driver.get('https://s2fs.axisbank.com/EFTClient/Account/Login.htm')
     email_box = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
     email_box.send_keys(email)
     pass_box = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
     pass_box.send_keys(password)
     submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id('loginSubmit')
     submit_button.click()
     time.sleep(3)
     File2393= driver.find_element_by_link_text('Checkbox For Item 919020028802393.csv')
     File2393.click()
     time.sleep(1)
     File3303= driver.find_element_by_link_text('Checkbox For Item 920020034873303.csv')
     File3303.click()
     time.sleep(1)
     download = driver.find_element_by_class('icomoon icon-download2 toolbar-button')
     download.click()
     print("File is been downloaded")
```

Comment: Often when a browser gets stuck after loading the URL it means that the driver version doesn't match the browser version. Make sure you've verified that they match.

Comment: What error do you get when you run the code? The link can't be opened in our browsers. Please make sure the link you provide is correct. Besides, you need to meet all the [Required Configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) before running IE selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a wait / delay before accessing the first element on the page.
You can simply add a sleep there, like this:

```
driver.get('https://s2fs.axisbank.com/EFTClient/Account/Login.htm')
time.sleep(10)
email_box = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
email_box.send_keys(email)
```

But it is better to use explicit waits

Answer (score 0):

well, this URL :-

```
https://s2fs.axisbank.com/EFTClient/Account/Login.htm
```

is not loading at all in my browser, but if it works for you then you can try with Explicit wait as below  :

```
options = webdriver.IeOptions()
options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
driver = webdriver.Ie('C:\Program Files (x86)\selenium-3.141.0\selenium\webdriver\ie\IEdriverServer.exe')

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://s2fs.axisbank.com/EFTClient/Account/Login.htm")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
email_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))
email_box.send_keys('email')
```

These would be the **imports** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the site is not reachable, you can try to use the correct URL to access the page,

Accessing the element, you could use the `explicitWait`

```
 email_box = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"element_XPATH")))
 email_box.send_Keys("UserName")
```

**import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```